# Issue while installing Bugzilla on Window 10

Tags: bugzilla

I have tried to install the Bugzilla-5.0.4 version in my Windows 10 OS system.

Also, I have installed **MySQL 8.0** version along to maintain the all Bug data assets. I have installed all plugin which were not install.

I have provided all database configuration in **localconfig** file.

But i am facing issue while running **checksetup.pl command** .
Few last lines taken from the CMD window while executing below command.

```
 c:\Bugzilla>perl checksetup.pl
 * This is Bugzilla 5.0.4 on perl 5.24.3
 * Running on Win10 Build 17134
 Checking perl modules...

.
.
.
.
.

Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.033
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v8.0.15

Adding new table groups...
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups (
        id      mediumint auto_increment PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name    varchar(255) N' at line 1 [for Statement "CREATE TABLE groups (
        id      mediumint auto_increment PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        description     mediumtext NOT NULL,
        isbuggroup      tinyint NOT NULL,
        userregexp      tinytext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        isactive        tinyint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
        icon_url        tinytext
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8"] at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 837.
        Bugzilla::DB::_bz_add_table_raw(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x913ec90), "groups", HASH(0x94cf7c8)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 796
        Bugzilla::DB::bz_add_table(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x913ec90), "groups", HASH(0x94cf7c8)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 509
        Bugzilla::DB::bz_setup_database(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x913ec90)) called at Bugzilla/DB/Mysql.pm line 558
        Bugzilla::DB::Mysql::bz_setup_database(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x913ec90)) called at checksetup.pl line 121
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved.**

The issue is mainly with current BugZilla 5.0.4 version. The scripts to generate the tables and all relevant asset in MySql 8.0 doesn't support UTF-8.

Thus i am looking for downgrading the MySQL version to 5x versions.

Below are external links for your reference.

```
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424043

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.community.india/LRwxmGJ2yNQ
```

Comment: 2 years later and the bug is still here. Apparently, it could also be because 'groups' became a reserved word in mysql 8